# rails form send many rows from same instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, nested-attributes, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a form to create a teacher, and in this form a have a table where I register the subjects that they can teach and some experience related of it.

But I dont know how to do it, in model, in controller and in view, because a have add nested fields to my teacher form, and use nested_attributes in model, and permit it in controller. but I dont know how to do it..

Model

```
class Tutor < User
  has_many :tutor_subjects
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tutor_subjects
end
```

In Controller i have the functions...

```
def create
    @tutor = Tutor.new(tutor_params)
    @tutor.save
end

def tutor_params
  params.require(:tutor).permit(:email,
        :first_name, 
        :last_name, 
        :gender, 
        :password,
        tutor_subjects_attributes: [])
  end
end
```

And the view

```
= simple_form_for [:admin, @tutor] do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  .col-md-8.col-sm-12
    .form-inputs
      = f.input :email
      = f.input :password
      = f.input :first_name
      = f.input :last_name
      = f.input :gender, collection: {Male: 1, Female: 2}, include_blank: "--Select gender--"

    %h2.well.well-sm Subjects
    %table.table
      %thead
        %tr
          %th Subject
          %th Experience
          %th Options
      %tbody#subjects
        = f.simple_fields_for :tutor_subjects_attributes do |s|
          %tr.subject0
            %td
              = s.input :subject_id, collection: Subject.all, label: false, include_blank: "--Select subject--", input_html: { id: "tutor_subjects_attributes_0_subject_id", name: 'tutor[tutor_subjects_attributes][0][subject_id]', class: "subject" }
            %td
              = s.input :experience, as: :text, label: false, input_html: { placeholder: "Type your experience", name: 'tutor[tutor_subjects_attributes][0][experience]', id: "tutor_subjects_attributes_0_experience" }
            %td.options
    = link_to :add_subject, "#", id: "add_subject", class: "btn btn-small btn-info"
```

Comment: so what is the problem? it is with `tutor_subjects_attributes` in strong parameters?

Comment: The problem is that i want to save the parameters to the nested model, sending many rows, but is not working

Comment: did try my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question right but it seems like you have problems dealing with strong parameters for nested attributes.

Your `tutor_params` should look like

```
def tutor_params
  params.require(:tutor).permit(
    :email,
    ...
    tutor_subjects_attributes: [
      :subject_id,
      :experience
    ]
  )
  end
end
```